# Editing data within associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations, editing

I have two associated tables. `Venues` and `Specials`. A `venue` can have many `specials`.
Once a user has created a venue I wish to allow them to create a special on the `venues#index` page. However I am struggling to figure out which is the best way to do this. I am weary of sending the `venue_id` as though params and then having the `venue_id` as a hidden table. From looking around I'm guessing the URL structure should be something like: `venues/1/special`. With '1' being the `venue_id` but am unsure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working and using `<%= link_to 'Add Special', new_venue_special_path(venue) %>` I get the correct URL `/venues/4/specials/new` however this produces `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"venues"}` is the error with the `def new` function in my `specials controller`